# Help me find this Science/Thriller movie involving an injured man and a mentally unstable woman

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

The movie I am looking for was made in the early 2000s and I only remember some parts of it:

1. A man is beaten unconscious while walking on the street by a bunch of gangmembers who then proceed to run away. An old man takes that man into his home where he regains consciousness but does not remember anything(he even forgets who he is). The old man takes a small piece of paper from the the man's pocket on which it is written 'MORGAN FIND ANNA'. The old man suggests that his name might be Morgan but he is not sure.
2. A troubled young woman walks into a hotel or restaurant and starts acting strange. The receptionist notices this and calms the lady down by offering her a cup of coffee. She tries to drink it in one go but burns her tongue. The receptionist then shows her how to drink it using two hands.
3. The same young woman seems to be having a nightmare in bed. She opens her eyes to see a young girl staring at her with white eyes(pretty freaky scene!).

The film is in English and (possibly)American.
I'll appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be '[Experiment](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468476/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)'. The synopsis from the previous link is:

> A young woman, Anna, walks the streets of a foreign city. Her mind full of pain. No memory of who she is. and plagued by nightmarish visions. Then she meets Morgan, a man who also has no memory. Forced to trust each other, the two feel a mysterious connection. A strong powerful feeling that bonds the two together Unknown to them their every action is being guided by unseen forces from the dark underground shadows of the city. Anna and Morgan are part of a frightening experiment that will have a terrifying and shocking conclusion.

From [this synopsis](http://www.hometheaterinfo.com/experiment_(2005).htm), we learn that there is a note:

> kindly baker tries to help her by giving her a sweet treat. Meanwhile Morgan is set upon by a group of thugs. He is rescued by an old man, Joseph (Nick Simons) who takes him to his flat while Anna tries to find a place to sleep in an alley. In Morgan’s pocket is a note ‘Morgan find Anna’. Anna happens into a currency exchange center and his helped by one of the clerks. When she passes out at the counter he takes her to rest in his place. There she has terrifying nightmares of men in a cinder block room. Back at Joseph’s place the elderly man goes into a back room while Morgan is sleeping. There is a younger man with all sorts of electronic monitoring devices who discusses with Joseph cryptic details of signal strength.

Mid 2000's would fit the time frame of when this movie was out.